# Eloquent ORM: any WHEREs in both relationship tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is possible to create this in `Eloquent ORM`?

```
SELECT * FROM 'data'
JOIN 'notice' ON 'data'.'id_notice' = 'notice'.'id' 
WHERE 'data'.'escalator'= 'yes' 
AND 'data'.'floors'= '2'
AND 'data'.'color'= 'white'
AND 'notice'.'price'= '50000' 
AND 'notice'.'city'= 'bardejov';
```

This is select from filter (random count of wheres).

**Notice Model:**

```
class Notice extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'notices';
    public function data() {
    return $this->hasOne('data'); 
    }
}
```

**Data Model:**

```
class Data extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'data';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public function notice() {
        return $this->belongsTo('notice', 'notice_id');
    }
}
```

My attempt:

```
$query = new Data;
  foreach()
    $query = $query->where('value', '=', $data['key']);
  endforeach
$result = $query->paginate(5);
```

But if where value is from table Notice - error: Unknown column...

Comment: Could you tidy up your SQL please, to make it easier to read? Try to keep all clauses and SQL specific language in capitals, but table names and field name should be surrounded by `

Comment: Done. Is it okay now?

Comment: Much better thank you.

Comment: To paste code, edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use join in Laravel, you can use query builder.

```
DB::table('data')
    ->join('notice', 'data.id_notice', '=', 'notice.id')
    ->where('escalator', 'yes')
    ->where('floors', 2)
    ->where('color', 'white')
    ->where('notice.price', 50000)
    ->where('notice.city', 'bardejov')
    ->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#joins

**OR:**

```
  Data::join('notice', 'data.id_notice', '=', 'notice.id')
    ->where('escalator', 'yes')
    ->where('floors', 2)
    ->where('color', 'white')
    ->where('notice.price', 50000)
    ->where('notice.city', 'bardejov')
    ->get();
```

Comment: The question is about `Eloquent` not `Query Builder`. `OP` wants the solution using `Eloquent ORM`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ([Check Eager Load Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading))

```
$data = Data::with(array('notice' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('price', 50000)->where('city', 'bardejov');
}))->where('escalator', 'yes')->where('floors', 2)->where('color', 'white')->get();
```